# ASP.NET MVC 4 Passing data to the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a form, with a textbox and some radio buttons (Only 1 radio button can be selected at once) so I want to submit to the controller, the person name and the radio button select, that is value 1, 2 or 3 depending on the selection (1:Programmer, 2:Project Manager, 3:Analyst) but I do not know how to pass only the value of the radio button selected instead of the value of all them. how to get rid of this?

for example, it person name is David and the selected radio button is Programmer, I want to pass (David,1), if selected radio button is Project Manager (David, 2) and if selected radio button is Analyst (David, 3) to the controller.

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("AddPerson", "AddToDatabase", FormMethod.Get))
   {
       <div id="Radio">
           @Html.TextBox("PersonName")
           @Html.RadioButton("Programmer")
           @Html.RadioButton("Project Manager")
           @Html.RadioButton("Analyst")
       </div>

       <input type="submit" value="@Resource.ButtonTitleAddPerson" />
   }
```

The controller signature is:

```
public bool AddPerson(string name, int charge)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `@Html.RadioButton` in other way:

```
@Html.RadioButton("Profession", "1") Programmer
@Html.RadioButton("Profession", "2") Project Manager
@Html.RadioButton("Profession", "3") Analyst
```

In your approach you receive three unconnected `radio buttons` with different `id`. And form thinks that they are different inputs and sends them all.

Comment: Many thanks again!It works like a charm! Sorry for my ignorance in asking maybe some trivial questions but I am compeletely new in web application programmig. A lot of thanks for helping me!